# emacs: org-mode, export (ox-html, ox-latex, Cannot open load file)

Tags: emacs, export, org-mode

There's a fragment from [a GTD setup](http://doc.norang.ca/org-mode.html):

---

;; Explicitly load required exporters

(require 'ox-html)

(require 'ox-latex)

(require 'ox-ascii)

---

Cannot open load file.

They should be a part of org-mode, shouldn't they? No files like ox-html.el appear to be present on the system (Linux, Emacs 24.3.1). Google results are scarce and confusing. Do I have to install something?

Answer (score 5):

These files are valid since Org 8. Are you sure you have that version installed?  If you use the builtin Emacs version, odds are high it's not the case. Then, install locally via ELPA, a tarball / zip file, or the Git development branches.

Comment: Yes, I had to follow [Getting Org-Mode With Git](http://doc.norang.ca/org-mode.html#GettingOrgModeWithGit) paragraph. It was my erroneous idea that Emacs 24+ features Org 8.x by default.